# how to map a postgres EARTH column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy and also alembic for migrations (and flask-sqlalchemy). I have a postgres table that uses the EARTH data type.

```
CREATE TABLE things
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name TEXT,
  earth_location EARTH
)
```

Here is my sqlalchemy mapping:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'things'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    earth_location = db.Column(???)
```

How do I map the earth column?

Will alembic migration be able to handle it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you happy with a read-only column, or do you require r/w?

Comment: Read-only is fine (for the predictable future at least), but definitely a bonus for the mapping to work during alembic migration creation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a column of type `earth` from the [*earthdistance* extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html) with SQLAlchemy is possible with:

- [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property), if you just wish to map the latitude and longitude values to attributes
- [`UserDefinedType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType), if you wish to have a full blown type that supports for example table creation

A `column_property` is somewhat straightforward to implement, but is limited to being read-only and requires some unorthodox syntax, if a declarative column is not available:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Float, column, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'things'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.UnicodeText, nullable=False)

_earth_location = column('earth_location', _selectable=Thing.__table__)

Thing.earth_location_latitude = column_property(func.latitude(
        _earth_location, type_=Float))
Thing.earth_location_longitude = column_property(func.longitude(
        _earth_location, type_=Float))
```

In order to produce a [`column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) with the right *_selectable* the attributes have to be added to the class `Thing` after it has been created, because the declaratively created `Table` is not available during creation in the class body. This allows for queries like

```py
session.query(Thing.earth_location_longitude).scalar()
```

to work as expected. Without the *_selectable* the issued SQL would be:

```py
SELECT longitude(loc)
```

Unfortunately this leaves the mapped table completely oblivious of the underlying column `things.earth_location` and so Alembic will also be none the wiser. Table creation in Alembic would have to be done by executing a raw SQL string.

A `UserDefinedType` has the advantage of being able to support table creation. Raw `earth` values are pretty useless in python context, so some back and forth with `ll_to_earth`, `latitude` and `longitude` functions is required. Combining a `UserDefinedType` with a `column_property` could perhaps provide a "best of both worlds" solution:

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import UserDefinedType
from sqlalchemy.orm import deferred


class EARTH(UserDefinedType):
    def get_col_spec(self, **kw):
        return 'EARTH'


class Thing(db.Model)
    __tablename__ = 'things'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    # defer loading, as the raw value is pretty useless in python
    earth_location = deferred(db.Column(EARTH))
    # A deferred column, aka column_property cannot be adapted, extract the
    # real column. A bit of an ugly hack.
    latitude = column_property(func.latitude(*earth_location.columns,
                                             type_=Float))
    longitude = column_property(func.longitude(*earth_location.columns,
                                               type_=Float))
```

Checking table creation:

```py
In [21]: t = Table('test', meta, Column('loc', EARTH))

In [22]: print(CreateTable(t))                        

CREATE TABLE test (
        loc earth
)
```

Adding a new `Thing`:

```py
>>> latitude = 65.012089
>>> longitude = 25.465077
>>> t = Thing(name='some name',
              earth_location=func.ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude))
>>> session.add(t)
>>> session.commit()
```

Note that a bound function call to `ll_to_earth` is provided as value.

A more sophisticated custom type supporting accessing lat and lon as attributes etc. would be entirely possible, but perhaps out of scope of this q/a.

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer and exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could upvote this twice! Thank you.

Comment: A word of caution about the `column(..., _selectable=...)` hack: it will not work with `aliased()` and the like.