# How to find all points in a radius in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am working on a project where i am using Flask, sqlalchemy and postgres. I am having three columns in my table, name, lat, lng. Now what i want is when a user sends a get request on api with location name, it should return all the locations from database which are in a certain radius to the city for e.g. say in 5 KM radius. I have already seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245931/how-to-map-a-postgres-earth-column-in-sqlalchemy). but its not what i want and also i am not getting how do i use earth_box and earthdistance with sqlalchemy. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use select geom st_within st_buffer(geom,radius) functions in postgis extension of postgresql